# Create master list adding iterations of values in another list with known interval in R

Tags: r, list, append

I have a solution that works, but would appreciate ideas to improve the code to avoid using loops if possible.

I have a list of values, this is read in from a csv file, but takes the form

```
startingvalues = c(1, 7, 20, 32, 47)
```

I want to create a new list, that reads in each of these starting values and adds the next 2 (or 7 or 15 etc.) numbers, then goes to the next.  For the above example this would be

```
 newlist = c(1,2,3,7,8,9,20,21,22,32,33,34,47,48,49)
```

I have code that works, but I suspect there is a more elegant way to do this.  I am not particularly worried about speed but would like to avoid the loop if there is a better way to do this.

```
newlist = c() # initialise an empty list

for (i in 1:length(startingvalues){
list1 = seq(startingvalues[i,1],startingvalues[i,1]+2, by = 1)
newlist = c(newlist,list1)
}
```

Any suggestions to improve my coding would be appreciated. This may be the best way to do this, however I suspect it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this

```
extend <- function(x,y) unlist(lapply(x, seq.int, length.out=y+1))
extend(startingvalues, 2)
# [1]  1  2  3  7  8  9 20 21 22 32 33 34 47 48 49
```

The first parameter is the vector of numbers and the second is how far you want to extend each number. We just us an `lapply` for the iteration and unlist the thing in the end. This is better than appending at each iteration which is not very efficient.

Here's another alternative

```
extend <- function(x,y) c(outer(0:y, x, `+`))
```

The `outer()` will build a matrix but we coerce back to a vector with `c()`.

Comment: This works perfectly if I enter startingvalues manually (as I've done in the example above), but I find if I read them in from a csv using      startingvalues<-read.csv("startingvalues.csv") this doesn't work, as it is a dataframe.  I tried using as.list(startingvalues) but still no luck.  I solved the problem by just defining as I did in the example, just thought I'd note this as I mentioned in the question that I was reading in from csv.

Comment: Well, presumably your data.frame has multiple columns. To extract the vector from the first column, you should use `startingvalues[[1]]`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `rep` with `+` to get the expected output

```
unique(sort(startingvalues + rep(0:2, each = length(startingvalues))))
#[1]  1  2  3  7  8  9 20 21 22 32 33 34 47 48 49
```

Or as @thelatemail mentioned replicating the 'startingvalues' and make use of the recycling would be better as `sort` can be avoided

```
s1 <- 0:2
rep(startingvalues, each=length(s1)) + s1
#[1]  1  2  3  7  8  9 20 21 22 32 33 34 47 48 49
```

Comment: Might be easier to go the other way - `rep(startingvalues, each=3) + 0:2`